# What are the trigger.io root urls?

Tags: trigger.io

Just trying this out as an alternative to phonegap and was just wondering what the root url locations are for each platform.

I know android is:

`file:///android_asset/src`

but could someone tell me what the other platforms root urls are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to use our [forge.tools.getURL](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/tools.html#geturl) method rather than hardcoding the root urls for each platforms.

As well as being easier to use the method, that makes your code resistant to any changes in the structure of our templates.

Comment: Whilst I do agree in most cases using that would probably be best, however I have an entire framework of shared code (from a web application which is already live) which rely upon knowing the root of the given application for a for dynamic resource loading. Also do I need to include any special javascript files to gain access to the forge.* objects as currently I am not using any JS functionality of forge but was planning to use the IsAndroid, IsIos etc. So anyway assuming everyone else in the world will use best practise, could you still let us know the root urls?

Comment: The Toolkit automatically adds the JS files you need to access the forge object so no need for anything extra there.